# Highlighting a row in a HTML bootstrap striped table

Tags: html, css

I have a table in HTML like this:

```
<tr class="highlight-row">
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>more data</td>
</tr>
```

I have the following CSS:

```
.highlight-row {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

However, when I run the app, it doesn't highlight the row in question. If I use the dev tools to force the style in, like this:

```
<tr class="highlight-row" style="background-color: blue;">
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>more data</td>
</tr>
```

It works fine. I've checked in JSFiddle, and this works in a new project. I've also checked the dev toos, and it looks like `background-color` is not a `computed property`.

My question is not "why isn't this working" - I have a feeling the answer is that it just can't access or see the class for some reason - but "what else can I do to debug it".

Comment: are you sure there is not something overlapping like css rule?

Comment: this is probably a specificity issue - if you look in dev tools at the class, can you see what is overriding the style?  You just need to make sure your css declaration is more specific

Comment: @SimoneRossaini It very likely is that. My question was how can I determine that.

Comment: @Pete how would I make the CSS declaration more specific? I thought that if you specified a class on an element, that was the same as directly setting the style

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity